# line plot: Using a vector to define different lineWidths

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I try to create a line plot that holds several lines in one variable `L`. It would be great if it's possible to assign a different line width for each line. The following throws an error message:

```
lWidth = {1;2;3;4;5;1;2;3;4;5;1;2;3}; %% 13 Elements, as <data> is 13x4 matrix

L = line([data(:,1) data(:,2)]', [data(:,3) data(:,4)]', ...
    'LineWidth', lWidth(:), 'Color', 'red');
```

> Error using line While setting the 'LineWidth' property of Line: Value
>   not a numeric scalar

Is there a way to use the lineWidths defined in the vector `lWidth`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that using `line` command arguments, but `set` function has a special syntax to handle that:

```
data = randn(13,4);
lWidth = {1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3}; %% 13 Elements, as data is 13x4 matrix

L = line([data(:,1) data(:,2)]', [data(:,3) data(:,4)]', 'Color', 'red');
set(L, {'LineWidth'}, lWidth(:));
```

Note that both property name and property values have to be cell arrays, and dimensions of the property cell array should be the same as those of the graphics handle array.

Comment: Thank you. I tried `set(L, 'LineWidth', lWidth(:));` which was quite close, actually.